# Pouchdb is not pushing documents on desktop (but pull works)

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I have a web app that worked fine both on desktop and mobile. It uses PouchDB to sync documents between instances, and as I said, it worked fine on mobile as well as desktop. But recently (not sure when) it stopped to work partially on desktop. This means that it pulls documents from the remote Cloudant server, but it is unable to push documents. The funny thing is that the same exact version is able to pull and push documents if I run it on my mobile chrome. I can't understand why.

The only issue that I can find is a failed get request to the remote server (returns a 404):
 https://username.cloudant.com/my_diary/_local/7lsY4rQGdHqHlZEO8Z9aLg%3D%3D?

Any advice (even on how to setup a better debug) is very welcome

Pouchdb version 5.4.5

EDIT:

Digging deeper I tried to replicate to an non existing database. The new database is created fine and filter and index documents are pushed correctly to it. But real documents are not being included in synchronization. Since putting documents manually (that's how I create indexes and filters) works, I suspect there is some kind of problem with the replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the sync issues were caused because the design document that was being used for filtering did not exist on the local database. It was hard to debug because:

- It was an old document and was being used before on the local
  databases. Some databases kept an old copy of it and therefore they
  worked
- On the newer databases the document did not exist, but
  synchronization was happening one-way, this confused me a lot. Not
  sure if this is normal.